# Google cloud platform disables the bot

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bots

I signed up for Google cloud platform added a card and got 300$ for free for 3 months. I uploaded my bot there using the app engine and got a link to access it. when I click on it and then close it, the bot works and responds to all my messages. But after a while it stops working again until I click on the link provided by google. What might be the problem? Is there any way to fix this? Please tell me how I can configure everything correctly so that my bot is not disabled. Maybe there are other free services? Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you see that your bot is disable? Is it resetted? Do you receive a 404? What do you see in the logs?

Comment: After a while it just stops responding to me until I go to the link that google gave me

Comment: What this link? how do you communicate with your bot? How do you reach it?

Comment: the bot is located in the social network Vkontakte, I just write messages to it. I hosted it on the Google cloud platform and when the deployment was complete google gave me a link to access it. When I go to it, it just loads an empty page, because my bot does not have html files.there is an index file.js in which everything is written. When I start this page, the bot starts working for me. I write to him and she responds. But after a while it stops responding until I click on the link again

Comment: Ok, my question is: when you write to him, what is the request flow? Do you use the base url provided by google? Which Google information did you have provided to vkontakte?

Comment: If it is hosted in App Engine Standard this behavior is expected as it can scale down to 0. Could you share the App.yaml

Answer (score 0):

It is because if app engine does not receive any requests it stops , it depends on your app engine settings when it sleeps , you can create 2 app engine servers and make them sending GET requests to each other so they will not sleep , this is what i did and it worked fine